# Search Function Only Sometimes Works

Tags: c, search

I'm trying to make a binary search function, and this is my current code:

```
bool _search(int value, int values[], int start, int end);

/*
 * Main search function
 */
bool search(int value, int values[], int n) {
    if(value < 0)
            return false;
    sort(values, n);
    return _search(value, values, 0, n);
}

bool _search(int value, int values[], int start, int end) {
    if(start < end) {
        // get the mean for comparing
        int mean = (start + end) / 2;
        if(value == values[mean]) // middle
            return true;
        else if(value < values[mean]) // left half
            return _search(value, values, start, mean - 1);
        else // right half
            return _search(value, values, mean + 1, end);
    } else
        return false;
}
```

I'm passing in random numbers to the program with a constant seed, and if the amount of numbers I'm passing in is 861 or below, it works correctly. However, if it gets 862 or higher numbers, it fails to find values. Weird. So I tried passing in a really high number, say, 1862. It found it! Okay... how about 2000? Nope. 3000? Yup. 4000? Nope. 5000? Nope. 6000? Yup.

What's going on here?

**Edit:** Also, if the array is only 3 elements and the element being searched for is the first element, it won't be found. There's definitely something wrong with the algorithm, I just can't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `search` function is incorrect: `start` is included, but `end` should be excluded.  When you recurse, you should not stop at `mean - 1`, but at `mean` otherwise, you will miss some entries and the search may fail when it shouldn't.

Here is corrected version:

```
bool _search(int value, int values[], int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        // get the mean for comparing
        int mean = (start + end) / 2;
        if (value == values[mean]) // middle
            return true;
        else
        if (value < values[mean]) // left half
            return _search(value, values, start, mean);
        else // right half
            return _search(value, values, mean + 1, end);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! That's a facepalm for me, as I figured I could just subtract one like I add one in the else block. Thanks!